# Running batch file from cmd line

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Currently I am in P directory as `P:\>`  and I have a bat file in my `H` drive as `H:\folderA\abc.bat` when I do a `CD` in command line like

```
P:\>CD H:\folderA\abc.bat
```

it says directory name is invalid.
Any suggestion what am I doing incorrectly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window and enter **`CD /?`**, then read what appears.

Comment: Nothing happens it stays in P drive without any error message.

Comment: You obviously didn't read the information fully, or understand it. Did you not read a sentence along the lines of _"Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current directory for a drive"_.

Comment: also, you are supposed to `cd` into a *folder*, not into a *file*.

Answer (score 0):

So, as  you have found out, CD H:\folderA\abc.bat is an invalid command. Why?

1. CD means change directory and abc.bat is a file, not a directory
2. Changing directories only works on a single drive. From P:, you would need to type `H:` and then `CD H:\folderA\` or you can use the /D switch with CD. I.E. `CD /D H:\folderA\`
3. You can run H:\folderA\abc.bat by typing `H:\folderA\abc.bat` from any drive (as long as there is no dumb code inside it expecting the batch to only be ran while the current working directory is the batch file's directory)